# Upgraded to 5.28.3 in WP - how to fix crash?

Tags: wordpress

Upgraded a WP site from 5.25 to 5.28.3 and now get this WP crash. I'm not familiar with WP so would appreciate any clues. The upgrade hadn't updated the file civicrm.php which is in plugins/civicrm folder so I replaced that with the 5.28.3 version.

Warning: include_once(/home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.compat.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 581

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.compat.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 581

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Compat' not found in /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:582 Stack trace: #0 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(379): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->include_files() #1 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->setup_instance('') #2 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-settings.php(409): do_action('plugins_loaded') #5 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-config.php(89): require_once('/home/fovps1e/p...') #6 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/fovps1e/p...') #7 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/fovps1e/p...') #8 /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/fovps1e/p...') #9 {main} thrown in /home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a WP error, it's a file that's either missing or has the wrong owner/permissions.

Look for `/home/fovps1e/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.compat.php`.  Is it present?  If not, you may need to unzip another copy of WordPress.  More likely, it's present, but its file ownership/permissions make it unreadable by whichever user is your PHP user.